# Is clarifai capable of logo recognition

Tags: clarifai

Is clarifai's approach to image detection capable / suitable for recognizing brand logos in images or will I have to use different approaches for that purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, give it try here: https://demo.clarifai.com/?models=brandlogos-v0.2&probabilityThreshold=0.1&showProbability=1

Documentation at https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/tag#models - the model name is `brandlogos-v0.2`

[image]

Comment: could I retrain that model to recognize new brands as well?

Comment: Is there any list of the 500 logos?

Comment: I am not there anymore, please contact jared@clarifai.com for support